# for loop of scatterplots, setting the colorbar of a scatterplot horizontally under each plot

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, matplotlib

I am really new to plots and matplotlib
I am trying to plot several scatterplots with a loop for data from a pandas data frame
each scatterplot will have on the x axis data from the columns and on the y axis will be the data from the last column
I can make the plots work, but my color bar is displayed on the right side of each plot
I would like to set the color bar horizontally, under each plot but unfortunately I lack the necessary knowledge.

my code looks like this:

```
num_cols = df.columns.to_list()[:-1]

for col in num_cols:
    df.plot.scatter(x = col, y = df.columns[-1], c=col, cmap='Paired', title=col, figsize = (5, 5))
```

current relust looks like this (sample of 1 plot from the loop):[current reslut]https://i.stack.imgur.com/m26wn.jpg

I tried a lines of code, but with no success.

I would like to have something like this (excuse my windows paint skills):[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlXrO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cmap_location to move it to bottom.

```
num_cols = df.columns.to_list()[:-1]

for col in num_cols:
    df.plot.scatter(x = col, y = df.columns[-1], c=col, cmap='Paired', title=col, figsize = (5, 5), cbar_location="bottom", cbar_mode="edge",
                    cbar_pad=0.25,
                    cbar_size="15%",)
```